# How to know if my winform is on top of other windows in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, z-order

I need to know if a specific window in my application is on top of all the other windows (including other applications).
I tried the `TopLevel` property but it tells if it is Toplevel within my application only, I would need to know related to other applications also.
How can it be done, preferring not using windows API?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help from MSDN
[GetTopWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633514.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, of course this can solve my problem, but I prefer a solution without using windows API.